# Permutations with MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, permutation, combinations

Is there a way to generate permutations with MapReduce?

input file:

```
1  title1
2  title2
3  title3
```

my goal:

```
1,2  title1,title2
1,3  title1,title3
2,3  title2,title3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a file will have `n` inputs, the permutations should have `n^2` outputs.  It makes sense that you could have `n` tasks perform `n` of those operations.  I believe you could do this (assuming only for one file):

Put your input file into the [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) to be accessible as read-only to your Mapper/Reducers.  Make an input split on each line of the file (like in WordCount).  The mapper will thus recieve one line (e.g. `title1` in your example).  Then read the lines out of the file in the DistributedCache and emit your key/value pairs:  with the key as your input and the values as each line from the file from DistributedCache.

In this model, you should only need a Map step.

Something like:

```java
public static class PermuteMapper
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{

private static final IN_FILENAME="file.txt";
          
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  String inputLine = value.toString();

  // set the property mapred.cache.files in your
  // configuration for the file to be available
  Path[] cachedPaths = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheArchives(conf);
  if ( cachedPaths[0].getName().equals(IN_FILENAME) ) {
     // function defined elsewhere
     String[] cachedLines = getLinesFromPath(cachedPaths[0]);
     for (String line : cachedLines)
       context.emit(inputLine, line);
  }
}
}
```