# How do I find all combinations of keys in a hadoop data set?

Tags: java, hadoop

My data is structured as follows:

```
A, 23
B, 324235
C, 123
D, 213
```

The example word count mapper has the following map function signature:

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

**Core Question:**

`Text value` is simply a single line from the input file, or a single key. How do I access all the keys at once? It seems the lines (and their expansion for later reduction) are not aware of the other input lines

**Example Usage:**

I'm looking to output all the combinations of IDs, which requires for the keys to "be aware of each other"

```
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD
```

**EDIT: Naive Approach/Intuition**

One way to accomplish it I believe is to use the mapper to project each line to map to a same key, and then in the reducer

Result of Mapper:

```
CONST_KEY, A
CONST_KEY, B
CONST_KEY, C
CONST_KEY, D
```

Reducer:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context){

//PSEUDO CODE
  for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
      for(int j = i+1; j < values.length; j++){
          String combo = concat(values[i], values[j]);
       }
  } 
}
```

But this seems crazy inefficient

Comment: This problem fits the category of permutations generated from MapReduce.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535878/permutations-with-mapreduce .

Comment: Even worse, the way you've written the reduce wont work because you can't access `values` like that. Hadoop doesnt give you access to the list of values, and you can iterate through values once. If you want to do it more, you need to store them in memory yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would just get the keyset, then do a nested for loop to create the result:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(yourmap.keySet());
List<String> results= new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < keys.length; j++)  {
        results.add(keys.get(i) + keys.get(j))
    }
}
```

Comment: Which works if you can read the entire file in memory, but it doesnt appear to extend to a map reduce model used by hadoop, unless I'm missing something terribly obvious (my fault my original question title was too vague, since edited)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have at least three options to achieve this:

1. `WholeFileInputFormat`

You can write a custom input format which gives the whole file as a record. You can see an example of this in Tom Whites code for his Hadoop book [here](https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/ch08-mr-types/src/main/java/WholeFileInputFormat.java).

2. Maintain state in the Mapper

As each record enters the Mapper, with each iteration generate the new combinations. Or a simpler approach would be to add the records to a list and once all of them have been read use the `cleanup()` method of the Mapper to generate all combinations.

3. Use a Reducer

You could emit each entry from the Mapper, using a common key and all values will enter the reduce as a list of values you can iterate through. You would then need to have logic to generate all the combinations.

The problem is really, that if you have multiple files and thus multiple mappers running in parallel, `1` and `2` dont work. `3` will work as long as the unique set of keys will fit in memory.